# How do I get the user ID from the $user_profile variable?

Tags: 7, users

How can I get the user ID and load the user with `user_load()` using the `$user_profile` variable in the *user-profile.tpl.php* template file?

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code in a module will make the user ID available to the *user-profile.tpl.php* template as `$user_id`.

```php
function mymodule_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
  $account = $variables['elements']['#account'];
  // Add the user ID into the user profile as a variable
  $variables['user_id'] = $account->uid;
  // Helpful $user_profile variable for templates.
  foreach (element_children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
    $variables['user_profile'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
  }

  // Preprocess fields.
  field_attach_preprocess('user', $account, $variables['elements'], $variables);
}
```

This means that you can then copy the *user-profile.tpl.php* template from the *modules/user* directory to your theme directory and change it to the following.

```html
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $user_id; ?>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the uid from $user_profile as it does not contain any information we can use to get the current user.

To get the current user's object, use the following:

```
global $user;
echo $user->uid;
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted the requested user not the current. Anyway, I've find another way to do

Answer (score 0):

The *user-profile.tpl.php* template file doesn't get a variable containing the user ID, nor a user object. The `$user_profile` variable contains what needs to be rendered for the user profile. [`template_preprocess_user_profile()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/7.x) retrieves the user object used for the profile, but it doesn't pass it to the template file, nor does it pass the user ID.

If the user ID is necessary in the *user-profile.tpl.php* template file, implementing [`hook_preprocess_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x) helps.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#account']) && isset($variables['elements']['#account']->uid)) {
    $variables['uid'] = $variables['elements']['#account']->uid;
  }
}
```

The template file can then use `$uid` to get the user ID.

Notice that copying other code from `template_preprocess_user_profile()` is not necessary: `template_preprocess_user_profile()` is executed before any preprocess and process functions, whenever they are implemented in modules or in themes. An implementation of `hook_preprocess_user_profile()` doesn't override/replace `template_preprocess_user_profile()`.